# Change "hosts" / "-h" Docker for Windows in daemon.json

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows, docker-desktop

I'm trying to change `daemon.json` on **Docker Desktop for Windows** (Windows 10 Aniversary latest updates installed) `1.13.0-rc5` so I can change the `"hosts": []` setting like this:

```
{
  "hosts": [
    "tcp://0.0.0.0",
    "http://0.0.0.0"
  ]
}
```

However, after change the settings using the settings app I got this error:

> Docker daemon failed with message:  unable to configure the Docker
>   daemon with file C:\ProgramData\docker\config\daemon.json:  the
>   following directives are specified both as a flag and in the
>   configuration file:  hosts: (from flag:
>   [npipe:////./pipe/docker_engine_windows],  from file: [tcp://0.0.0.0
>   http://0.0.0.0])

Looks like the daemon is already started with `-H` flag and the json config isn't merged with it.

So, how can we change those settings by either json file or change the dockerd startup parameters?

Answer (score 2):

You have a similar case with [issue 22339](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/22339):

> This is expected; you cannot specify options both as a flag and in the configuration file (`daemon.json`).
>   If you change your `DOCKER_OPTS` to `DOCKER_OPTS=""` and restart, then it should work. We explicitly don't "merge" these configurations.

Or add in docker.conf

```
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/path/to/dockerd
# or
ExecStart=/path/to/dockerd daemon
```

But the official stance remains:

> There's no bug in the `systemd` configuration, to override defaults in a `systemd` unit file, you can use a drop-in file, as described in "[Custom Docker daemon options](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/systemd/#/custom-docker-daemon-options)".
>
> Producing an error if both a flag and an option in `daemon.json` are provided was a design decision when implementing that (in general, flags should always have precedence over configuration files); automatically merging options was not an option, as this would lead to unexpected results (was the intent to override an option, or to add to an option?)

[PR 27473](https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/27473) was rejected, for [issue 21559](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/21559).

Comment: Thanks for reply. I saw that pr/issue as well. However, I'm on Windows. How can I change he default dockerd prameters so I can add the -H there instead of in the file?

Comment: I'm also looking for this - pretty annoying that Docker for Windows seems to start the service with the -H flag. Seems like putting this as a default into the daemon.json would have worked instead?

Comment: Not just a windows thing. On a ubuntu 16.04 box, which ships with systemd, the daemon is started with command line options `-H fd://`, which conflicts with any host setting in daemon.json. If you then try to naively create a systemd override file to change the `ExecStart` directive (i.e. with `systemctl edit docker`), then systemctl complains that the `Service has more than one ExecStart setting`. The fix then is to, counterintuitively, add an empty `ExecStart=`, followed by the new setting `ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd`. See: [Issue 14491](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/14491). not fun.